# mysqld.exe has stopped working. Trying to start mysql in XAMPP

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

Right now I am learning how to code HTML and PHP and use SQL. I am using XAMPP for mysql. Whenever I try to start mysql I always get an error. This is the error log.

```
2018-02-24 17:22:30 f04 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2018-02-24 17:22:30 3844 [Note] InnoDB: innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool at least up to 20MB.

2018-02-24 17:22:31 3844 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2018-02-24 17:22:31 3844 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2018-02-24 17:22:31 3844 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2018-02-24 17:22:31 3844 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used for memory barrier
2018-02-24 17:22:31 3844 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2018-02-24 17:22:31 3844 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2018-02-24 17:22:31 3844 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2018-02-24 17:22:31 3844 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-02-24 17:22:31 3844 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
2018-02-24 17:22:31 3844 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibdata1 size to 10 MB
2018-02-24 17:22:31 3844 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 size to 5 MB
2018-02-24 17:22:31 3844 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
2018-02-24 17:22:31 f04 InnoDB: Error: Write to file C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101 failed at offset 0.
InnoDB: 512 bytes should have been written, only 0 were written.
InnoDB: Operating system error number 87.
InnoDB: Check that your OS and file system support files of this size.
InnoDB: Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
InnoDB: FormatMessage: Error number 87 means 'The parameter is incorrect.

'.
InnoDB: Error number 87 means 'Unknown error'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2018-02-24 17:22:31 f04  InnoDB: Operating system error number 87 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
 InnoDB: Operation os_file_write_func to file D:\win32-packages\build\src\storage\xtradb\os\os0file.cc and at line 5097
2018-02-24 17:22:31 3844 [ERROR] InnoDB: File C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_logfile101: 'os_file_write_func' returned OS error 287. Cannot continue operation
180224 17:22:31 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.

To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs

We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

Server version: 10.1.30-MariaDB
key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=1001
thread_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 787129 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!my_parameter_handler()
mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
mysqld.exe!?compare_ulonglong@@YAHPB_K0@Z()
mysqld.exe!no_key()
mysqld.exe!no_key()
mysqld.exe!no_key()
mysqld.exe!no_key()
mysqld.exe!no_key()
mysqld.exe!no_key()
mysqld.exe!no_key()
mysqld.exe!?compare_ulonglong@@YAHPB_K0@Z()
mysqld.exe!?compare_ulonglong@@YAHPB_K0@Z()
mysqld.exe!?str_result@Item@@UAEPAVString@@PAV2@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?ha_initialize_handlerton@@YAHPAUst_plugin_int@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?plugin_init@@YAHPAHPAPADH@Z()
mysqld.exe!?init_net_server_extension@@YAXPAVTHD@@@Z()
mysqld.exe!?win_main@@YAHHPAPAD@Z()
mysqld.exe!?mysql_service@@YAHPAX@Z()
mysqld.exe!strxnmov()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath()
ntdll.dll!RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath()
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

I have tried deleting the `ibdata1`, `ib_logfile1` and `ib_logfile0` and the `mysql_error` in the `C:\xampp\mysql\data` folder but it hasn't helped. I dont know what to do and how to fix it. I have read other questions on this website and topic but none of the solutions given help me. Please help!

Comment: *"Check also that the disk is not full"*  Have you verified this?

Comment: I have checked that my laptop is not running out of storage and I am not. I still have enough space left.

Comment: How much RAM is on this server?  Please post your complete my.cnf/ini.  Last crisis was BaseThreadInitThunk - in English, could not create a thread and it looks like a trouble NamedObjectPath contributed.  Follow the advice of the last two lines about crashing.html.